# How do I parse a JSON map into an Apex Map?

Tags: apex, json

I am trying to parse the following JSON format into a Object.

```
{
  "info1": "blah blah",
  "info2": "blah blah2",
  "info3": 1391673663,
  "info4": "blah4",
  "info5": {
    "AAA": 0.1,
    "BBB": 0.3,
.....
  }
}
```

But the problem is under [info5] list, name like "AAA", "BBB" and their related values are dynamic and always changing.

How should I make my Object to satisfy this kind of structure?
I want to put those values into a Map if possible.

So that I can easily get "AAA" and its Related values.

Any input will be so helpful for me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You will have to use [JSON.deserializeUntyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) method that will deserializes a JSON representation of an appliance object into a map that contains primitive data types and further collections of primitive types. Something like below should work:

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
Map<String, Object> m2 = (Map<String, Object>) m.get('info5');
List<decimal> d = new List<decimal>();

for(String s:m2.keyset()) {
    decimal t = (decimal) m2.get(s);
    d.add(t);
}
```